# Configuring php.ini file to install Composer

Tags: mamp, php

I am trying to install gitlist from github. I have some trouble installing it, so the doc says that I should configure php.ini this way

detect_unicode = Off
phar.readonly = Off
phar.require_hash = Off

I did it but when installing Composer, I am still told to set detect_unicode to Off. I restarted MAMP, and phpinfo() tells me phar.readonly and phar.require_hash are indeed set to Off, but I have no infos telling me detect_unicode is set to Off. I only have zend.detect_unicode set to On.

How can I set my configuration to have detect_unicode indeed set to Off ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had the same problem than you. I found this article : http://simon-davies.name/mamp/using-composer-with-mamps-version-of-php and it solve it.

Hope it will help.

Comment: Thanks, in a way that's what I finally did, using MAMP pro to set the right php.ini file, because I had lot versions of it. I took php.ini.default, I set it and renamed it php.ini